# On a special block diagonalization of linear operator in dimension at least $4$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, block-matrices

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\dim V\ge 4$ . Let $T: V\to V$ be a linear operator.

Is it necessarily true that there exists a basis $\mathcal B$ (depending on $T$) of $V$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal B$ is block diagonal with each block size either $1\times 1$ or $2\times 2$ ?

Comment: No. Consider any nilpotent Jordan block of size $\dim V$ for instance. You are probably thinking about something like the [*real Jordan form*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices) (whose diagonal sub-blocks have sizes $1$ or $2$), but mistaking it as a block-diagonal matrix.

Comment: @user1551: I don't see why your example cannot be written in the particular block diagonal form I ask ...

Comment: @user102248 The first comment was not giving you a (specific) counterexample so your comment does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not necessarily true.  As a counterexample, take $T$ to be the map $x \mapsto Ax$ where
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0}.
$$
Note that $T$ satisfies $T^4 = 0$ but $T^2 \neq 0$.  Now, suppose for the purpose of contradiction that the matrix $B$ of $T$ relative to a basis $\mathcal B$ is block-diagonal and that each block is either $1 \times 1$ or $2 \times 2$.  Note that a block diagonal matrix satisfies
$$
B^k = \pmatrix{B_1 \\ & \ddots \\ & & B_m}^k = \pmatrix{B_1^k \\ & \ddots \\ & & B_m^k}, \quad k = 1,2,3,\dots.
$$
Because $T^4 = 0$, we must have $B^4 = 0$, which means that $B_j^4 = 0$ for all $j$.  If $B_j$ is $1 \times 1$, it is clear that $B_j = 0$.  On the other hand, if $B_j^4$ is $2 \times 2$, then $B_j^4 = 0$ implies that $B_j^2 = 0$.  Thus, every block of $B$ satisfies $B_j^2 = 0$, which means that $B^2 = 0$.

On the other hand, $T^2 \neq 0$, which means that $B^2 \neq 0$.  We have reached a contradiction.